# User forms and dynamic look into table, is this possible?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, datatable

User forms and dynamic look into table, is this possible?

[image: Screenshot example]

I have a table that dynamically changes. I'm trying to make a user form that goes into the three options of this table.

I tried to photoshop what I was aiming for.

I just don't know if VBA can dynamically look up B2:B13 because the topics can change.

Link to workbook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ST3a9i3hKCWHDRnPb_167F2L547EisxT/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can [add controls to a userform on runtime dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980677/how-to-create-controls-dynamically-at-runtime): But I see no advantage at all in using such a userform over editing the table directly (as it shows exactly the same data). Maybe you can work with hiding column D and locking the sheet except column C where the users should be able to input data. After exam just let your macro unhide column D and you are able to put the scores. Much easier than a userform.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be done, but it seems like you are really over-engineering this.  Why not convert a data set to a table, which dynamically increases and decreases in size as the data elements change?

Creating a Table within Excel

```
Open the Excel spreadsheet.
Use your mouse to select the cells that contain the information for the table. 
Click the "Insert" tab > Locate the "Tables" group.
Click "Table". A "Create Table" dialog box will open. 
If you have column headings, check the box "My table has headers".
Verify that the range is correct > Click [OK].
Resize your columns to make the headings visible.
```

Also, see this:

https://exceljet.net/excel-tables

Or, reference the entire column/row, rather than a specific range, and use something like INDEX/MATCH, or whatever you need.